# Check which files in directory A are already contained somewher in directory structure B

Tags: files, directory-structure, delete

I have a neatly organized folder structure with subfolders which contains jpegs (directory structure B). I also have several unorganized folders of jpegs (directory A).

I would like to delete all files in directory A that are already somewhere in directory structure B (duplicates), so that I can manually sort away only the remaining files in A into B.

What would be a good approach to do that in an efficient way?

Comment: You can try `fdupes`.

Comment: If the filenames are the same, `diff dirA dirB` will show you what files only exist on one side

Comment: And I guess some `rsync` flags will do what you want aswell

Comment: I found the awesome tool "Czkawka" which works well for my purpose. Thanks for all your Ideas!